# How to pass the result of yank to find-file?

Tags: find-file, kill-ring

So I wanted to basically copy the current selection, then yanking it into `find-file`, as when using:

- `C-SPC`: `set-mark-command`
- `M-w`: `kill-ring-save`
- `C-x C-f`: `find-file`
- `C-y`: `yank`

While that works great, I wanted to make it into a command if possible, so I tried and came up with this so far:

```lisp
(define-advice kill-ring-save (:around (old-fun &rest args) highlight)
  "Save the text selection and keep the selection highlight."
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (apply old-fun args)))

(defun find-file-region ()
  (interactive)
  (execute-extended-command nil "kill-ring-save" nil)
  (call-interactively 'find-file)
  (yank nil))
```

Now, I'm using this particular `kill-ring-save` function, mostly because I found it work better than the default one, but that's just what I noticed in my workflow. *And also because i didn't know how to use the default one in this particular endeavor*

So this doesn't obviously work, my guess being is that it doesn't run `yank` after running `(call-interactively 'find-file)`

I've tried:

- using default `find-file` but since it require a filename and doesn't just "open with current directory of the buffer/file" like it usually do if used in the keybinding, that didn't work either.
- was replacing `(call-interactively 'find-file)` with `(execute-extended-command nil "find-file" nil)` but it did the same thing as far as I'm aware (that is, it didn't work either).

### Question

How could I pass the current selection/region (from `C-SPC`) to `find-file` and open the file whether it exists or not? (since usually, I recall `find-file` creates the file if it doesn't exist, which is what I want too).

Don't really care if it's done interactively or in the background, as I just did that to tinker around and see if it'll work.

Comment: Elisp tag doesn't apply here. Please read [Elisp tag info](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: `(find-file (car kill-ring))`?

Comment: @Muihlinn Thanks, didn't know :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed edit on my post btw! I'll learn from it so i can make better post in the future @Drew

Comment: You're welcome. That's the idea. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem lies in yanking nowhere useful because it'll yank after `call-interactively` returns, not *inside* its execution.

Basically you don't need anything else than calling this if you already have done <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> on region, as it actually adds it to  kill-ring.

```lisp
(defun find-file-region()
 (interactive)
 (find-file (substring-no-properties (car kill-ring))))
```

The idea is passing the equivalent of `pop`'ing the `kill-ring` without discarding it.

Or you can skip the kill-ring steps using region's content making use of a similar approach.

```lisp
(defun find-file-region()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
    (let ((str (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))
      (find-file str))
    (message "No region active")))
```

Comment: I couldn't make the first code example work but the latter one work perfectly (the first one didn't match after doing `eval-region` but the second one did work) Thanks!

Comment: I forgot making it interactive so you cannot call it with `M-x`, sorry. It's corrected now.

Comment: No worries, the second block worked great anyway :D Thanks a lot!