# How to add a specific extension on filename for new files?

Tags: find-file

Say i create a new file using `find-file` (by typing a non-existing filename, since it create a newfile with said filename) How could i add the .org extensions at the end automatically?

I heard of hooks on emacs but i wasn't sure if this was the solution, so here i am.

To Clarify: I don't mind if every new files created have a .org extensions, as i center my workflow around `org-mode` like a lots of others do. Here `find-file` is just to be specific, but in general, i wouldn't mind if it happen even outside of using `find-file`.

Comment: Are you using `C-xC-f` or are you using your own command that makes use of `find-file`? If the latter, then you can use this in the `interactive` spec, to read the file name: `(read-file-name "File: " nil (expand-file-name ".org") nil)`. That will insert the directory`/.org`, and put your cursor before the dot so you can type the file name.

Comment: Both :), I'm using the second code block on the accepted answer of my previous [post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/58433/28919)

Comment: But i don't mind if every new files have the .org extensions, since i always end up using it, with or without using `find-file` to be honest.

Comment: mind showing an example more detailed using your aforementioned suggestion? just curious @Drew :)

Comment: `(defun my-find-file (filename &optional wildcards)
  "..."
  (interactive
   (list (read-file-name "File: " nil (expand-file-name ".org") nil) t))
  (find-file filename wildcards))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
(defun add-default-extension (retval)
  (let ((filename (car retval))) ; retval is (filename t)
    (if (or (file-exists-p filename)
            (file-name-extension filename))
        retval
      (message "Adding default .org extension")
      (list (concat filename ".org") t))))

(advice-add 'find-file-read-args :filter-return #'add-default-extension)
```

(Well, it would be more accurate to say "I wouldn't do it, but if I had to, I'd do it this way:" :P)

---

**EDIT**: The above answer only add `.org` to file names typed interactively at the `find-file` prompt, but I read in the comments to the question that you are actually not using `find-file` but this function instead:

```
(defun find-file-region()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
    (let ((str (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))
      (find-file str))
    (message "No region active")))
```

In that case, just add the extension there:

```
(defun find-file-region ()
  (interactive)
  (if (region-active-p)
      (let ((str (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))))
        (find-file (if (or (file-exists-p str)
                           (file-name-extension str))
                       str
                     (concat str ".org"))))
    (message "No region active")))
```

Comment: Oh, just because it leaves you no easy way of creating a new file without an extension, @Fólkvangr

Comment: Thanks, work great! @Omar
and yeah, i think i wouldn't recommend (even myself) to do this, unless you always use the same extensions like me ( i always use `org-mode` everywhere anyway) @Fólkvangr